# Semi-liquid Atmosphere - Other questions

Tags: science-based, technology, physics, environment, culture

Part 4 (last) of [Semi-liquid Atmosphere Questions:](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28140/how-would-a-semi-liquid-atmosphere-affect-the-climate-environment-ecology-etc)

This part I'm not really considering too strongly yet. But feedback is still awesome.

4. Other stuff. For future. Possibly.

   - Landforms

     - How might this affect landform formation, erosion, and the like?
     - Sandstorms and deserts? Since these rely heavily on fluid dynamics as it is, I'd imagine it's be very similar, if only different in sand-erosion and collection. But a sandstorm might function differently. Note also, dust devils. What about tundras?
     - Volcanic activity? How would this affect ejected ash-travel? I just wonder, it seems it would make it very hard to settle... which could be catastrophic. I'd rather not have that.
   - Ecology - I've mostly put this off, but I do want to somewhat fuzz the 'fish-fowl barrier'. Animals I can mostly guess I think... if I add some interesting effects, like air-bladders, or tad-pole-like evolutions, or sky-plankton.  Other things, like the 'sea-mount' effect, where an underwater mountain will kick up nutrients leeward and become a nexus of life? Plants, I don't know how or if things would change much.
   - Anthropology - Again, for later. But I'm thinking the effects on community development? Say, a small fishing village. Or technology? Like gliders, or simple ballast/wing systems allowing for multi-level or submarine-like naval warfare. Lamps that 'float' by capturing the flame. Etc.

Comment: This one is really broad, I have to say. You could make each bullet its own question.

Comment: Landform, check. Volcanic activity, check. You *really* need to read *Close to Critical*.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_to_Critical

Comment: Sounds cool.
Not sure if I want a 'hell-world' any more than 'magical underwater adventure!' though.